# Fake CGI environment for an external program

Tags: perl, unit-testing

Suppose I have a CGI script, not necessarily written in Perl, and I want to unit test that.

Of course I can just use a web-server and LWP::UserAgent but I think that's a bit of overkill.

So, how can I run a CGI program from within perl? E.g. in pseudocode:

```
my $reply = fake_cgi("/path/to/prog.cgi", foo=>"bar", count=>1);
like ($reply->content, qr/<title>/, "Title is always present");
```

I've found [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583405/how-can-i-run-my-perl-cgi-script-without-apache/2584025#2584025) but I'd still prefer a ready-made module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [`CGI::Test`](http://p3rl.org/CGI%3a%3aTest) is what your looking for. I haven't used it my self but it's docs say,

> The CGI::Test module provides a CGI regression test framework which allows you to run your CGI programs offline, i.e. outside a web server, and interact with them programmatically, without the need to type data and click from a web browser.

and

> Note that the CGI scripts you can test with CGI::Test need not be implemented in Perl at all. As far as this framework is concerned, CGI scripts are executables that are run on a CGI-like environment and which produce an output.

Comment: Yes, that's it. It has `Test::*` incompatible `ok()` but that's probably `ok()`.

Answer (score 1):

A CGI program can be executed like a normal application. It takes its input params from STDIN and ENV (environment variables). So you have to call with the properly variables, and read the STDOUT of the program.

Comment: Right, just like the link in OP suggests. That's what I'll do if there's no module that already does what I need.